# Teradata Query using syscalendar

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

Need query to get below output.Kindly help

[output of query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1tpm.jpg)

I have tried it but unable to get it.

Thanks,
Amar

Comment: What are you trying to actually do? And what have you tried?

Comment: What are the rules defining business days, Mon-Fri? What about holidays?